# java iterating through class variables inside a class

Tags: java, generics

There is class called SuperSettings.java as follows:

```
public SuperSettings{
SettingsClass1 var1;
SettingsClass2 var2;
SettingsClass3 var3
String str1;
String str2;
}

public SettingsClass1 {
SubSettingsClass1 sVar1;
SubSettingsClass2 sVar2;
}
public SettingsClass2 {
SubSettingsClass3 sVar3;
SubSettingsClass4 sVar4;
}
```

I need to iterate through the variables inside SuperSettings class and also the variables that are present inside the SettingsClass1 and SettingsCLass2.
I tried something like this:

```
private static final Class<?>[] supportedFormats = {SuperSettings.class.getClass()};

for (java.lang.Class t : supportedFormats)
{       
    System.out.println("Class VALUE :"+t);
    for(int i=0;i<supportedPersistenceFormats.length;i++)
    System.out.println("Supported formats:" 
      +supportedFormats.getClass().getName());
}
```

but i get teeh output as follows:
Class VALUE :class java.lang.Class
Supported formats: [Ljava.lang.Class;

I am expecting values as :
var1 var2 var 3 str1 str2.

What needs to be done to get the expected behaviour?

Comment: You need to read on Java reflection. There are just too many concepts you need to understand first. Try https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/

Comment: whats the difference between                                                         Class<?>[] supportedFormats = {SuperSettings.class.getClass()};      and     Class t1= SuperSettings.class; ?

Comment: you can see https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/class_getclasses.htm